# Sort words alphabetically in each row of a dataframe python

Tags: python, string, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a column in dataframe which contains string values as given below:

```
sortdf=pd.DataFrame(data= {'col1':["hello are you","what happenend","hello you there","issue is in our program","whatt is your name"]})
```

I want to sort each word in a element alphabetically.

Desired output:

```
    col1
0    are hello you
1   happenend what 
2   hello there you 
3    is in issue  our program
4   is name whatt your
```

I tried doing this using below code:

```
sortdf['col1']. sort()
```

But this code doen not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with an anonymous `lambda` function:

```
sortdf['col1'] = sortdf['col1'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(sorted(x.split())))
```

`pd.Series.sort` is inappropriate because (a) this sorts series elements rather than words within series elements, and (b) the method has been deprecated in favour of `sort_values`.

The idea is to split a string into a list of words, sort alphabetically, then rejoin into a string.

Result:

```
                      col1
0            are hello you
1           happenend what
2          hello there you
3  in is issue our program
4       is name whatt your
```

Alternatively, a list comprehension may be more efficient:

```
sortdf['col1'] = [' '.join(sorted(x)) for x in sortdf['col1'].str.split()]
```

Comment: Maybe faster than apply ? `list(map(lambda x : ' '.join(sorted(x)),sortdf.col1.str.split().tolist()))
`

Comment: @Wen, Yep, probably. The list comprehension I added should be even faster than `map` + `lambda`.